# Calling variables back to main

Tags: java, methods

I am supposed to find the area of a pentegon in a method and call it back to main so it can be printed to a `.txt` file. I got the everything to work in the main perfectly then when i tried break it up and put the area equation into a method i keep getting this error: 
`The method pentegon(int) in the type ABhw4part4 is not applicable for the arguments ()`

At the line of code `double area = pentegon();`

(ABhw4part4 is the project name)

something seems to go wrong when I try calling the answer to the equation back to the main

I am having a similar problem with another problem involving strings and char

I would be grateful for any help

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ABhw4part4 {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

/* Write a method to calculate the area of a pentagon.

Call this method from MAIN and print the result.
Create a file and write all data to the file.

Expected Output:

Input the number of sides: 5
Input the side: 6
The area of the pentagon is 61.93718642120281
Expected file content:
Number of sides: 5
Side: 6*/

File myFile = new File("C://temp//ABhw4part4.txt");


if (myFile.createNewFile() == true) {
System.out.println("file is created");
} else {
System.out.println("file already exists");
}
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(myFile);
Scanner sides = new Scanner (System.in);
int nos, sl;


System.out.println("enter the number of sides");
nos = sides.nextInt();
writer.println(nos);

System.out.println("enter the length of the sides");
sl = sides.nextInt();
writer.println(sl);


double area = pentegon();
System.out.println("area of the pentagon="+ area);
writer.println(area);
writer.close();

}
static double pentegon(int sl) {
double A = (5 * Math.pow(sl, 2)) / (4 * Math.tan(Math.PI /5));
return A;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass an argument to your method pentagon. Right now you are calling it like this

```
double area = pentegon();
```

Where it should be called like this

```
double area = pentegon(sl);
```